# Binding symbols and querying symbol values in Prolog

Tags: variables, binding, prolog

I have some difficulty doing some very basic things in SWI Prolog. For starters, how to I have a function that binds a symbol to a value? Here's what I tried, I don't know if it's correct:

```
bind(Name) :- assert(Name = 'A').
```

Now if I run `bind(Test).` in an interpreter I would like the symbol `Test` to be bound to the value `'A'`. Is this the way to do it? If it is, how do I then query the value of the symbol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking about such a very basic thing as unification in Prolog?

If you have a predicate

```prolog
bind('A').
```

defined, then in any other predicate, after calling

```prolog
.... ,    %// #1
bind(X),  %// #2
....
```

`X` will hold `'A'` as value below the point #2, until backtracking occurs (if any) back above the point #2.

But there's no need for a separate `bind` predicate for that. Unification is signified with [`=/2` built-in operator](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28%3D%29/2), and the same effect is achieved with

```prolog
.... ,    %// #1
X = 'A',  %// #2
....
```

If you try this in SWI Prolog console,

```
1 ?- X = 'A'.
X = 'A'.
```

you can access it later as

```
2 ?- Z = $X.
Z = 'A'.
```

But if you want something more tangible, you should assert it into the database, under some functor name of your choice, as you're advised in CapelliC's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Prolog has a *relational* data model. Each predicate can be seen as a table of a relational database. Then your association could be modelled with a binary predicate:

```
:- dynamic symbol_value/2.
```

to store a binding:

```
bind(Name, Value) :- assert(symbol_value(Name, Value)).
```

to query a value:

```
?- symbol_value(S, V).
```

Joins are simply conjunctions:

```
% two different symbols with same value ?
?- symbol_value(S1, V), symbol_value(S2, V), S1 \= S2.
```

Functions doesn't really exists in Prolog. Coherently with a relational model, should be seen as possibly infinite relations. For practical purposes, these are implemented for arithmetic evaluation. A *builtin* named is/2 introduce arithmetic evaluation, a sublanguage, where we have functions like +, sin, etc...